# Estimate the discounts...

Tags: percentages

Here is a problem on discount estimation,,

> If marked price of an article is $\frac{8}{5}$ times cost price and its selling price is at least $\frac{4}{5}$th the cost price then discount percentage is...

multiple choices are possible...

options:

A) $25$
B) $40$
C) $50$
D) $60$
E) $80$

I am somewhat confused...

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Say the cost price is $x$,

the maximum possible discount price =  $\frac{8}{5}(x) - \frac{4}{5}(x)$

$\implies $maximum possible discount percent = $\dfrac{\frac{8}{5}(x) - \frac{4}{5}(x)}{\frac{8}{5}(x)}\times 100$

Simplify and see which options are not greater than this percent

Comment: you're welcome :)